# Can I make my own fuel pump gasket?

Tags: fuel-system, gasket, seal

The gasket around the in-tank fuel pump on my car disintegrated and is leaking.

I can't seem to find a new replacement anywhere.

Could I just cut my own out of a piece of rubber or cork?

Comment: Make it from material that is designed to do the job such as [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Flexoid-Gasket-Paper-Set-Sheets/dp/B00A1B6U6G/) (possibly with a sealant).

Comment: Note that part of smog testing is pressurizing the fuel tank and making sure it can hold pressure.  A post-2000 car will even blow a code for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the original gasket was rubber and you have some rubber of the correct thickness that does not deteriorate when in long term contact with fuel (not all can) then there is no reason why you couldn’t make one yourself out of rubber.

I don’t think cork will be suitable or easy to work with.

Often these gaskets are made from a special oil resistant paper/card like this -
[image]

This is readily available in different thickness sheets for DIY gasket making. [For example on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Flexoid-Gasket-Paper-Set-Sheets/dp/B00A1B6U6G/ref=sr_1_7?crid=3VOY6GBJ0WADD&keywords=Gasket%20paper&qid=1659167443&sprefix=gasket%20paper%2Caps%2C75&sr=8-7)

Comment: Recommending crud of random quality from 3rd party Amazon sellers (which ~= eBay) is a terrible idea.  I would try McMaster-Carr or Grainger, or a chandlery.